# Why cpu number is limited?

Tags: cpu

seeing this log:

```
APIC: NR_CPUS/possible_cpus limit of 64 reached.
```

but I didn't set any limitation on CPU number.

Comment: What does `grep NR_CPUS= /boot/config-$(uname -r)` say?

Comment: got it, kernel config set it

Answer (score 1):

Not everyone needs a kernel that is capable of handling the absolute maximum of 8192 CPUs, and support for each CPU core costs about 8KB of memory.

Being prepared to handle thousands of CPU cores when you actually only have tens of them also adds some processing overhead in parts of the process scheduling code, so setting more modest limits for kernels that are not intended to run a supercomputer will make the kernel more efficient.

You might want to see if your distribution offers alternative kernel packages for systems with a large number of CPUs, or if you are using a version of a distribution that's older than your CPU model, consider upgrading to a newer major release of the distribution if possible.

Sometimes just updating your current distribution to its latest patch level may include an updated kernel configuration that will support more CPUs.

If those options aren't available to you, or if your system is new and/or exceptionally high-performance one, it might be necessary to build your own custom kernel for it, at least until the distribution maintainers will adjust their kernel configurations to match the increasing CPU core counts.

The CPU clock frequencies have reached some pretty hard physical limits with the current technologies, so packing more cores into a single physical CPU module is now one of the main ways of increasing CPU performance.